# Updating model programmatically in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to do the following:

```
angular.module("controllers", [])
    .controller("FooController", function($scope) {
        $scope.foo = {};
        $scope.foo['bar'] = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
            $scope.foo['bar']++;
        }, 100);
} );
```

And then, I display the value of `foo.bar` in my view using

```
<div> {{ foo.bar }} </div>
```

The initial value is displayed correctly, but it is never updated. The callback within setInterval is called correctly and the value of `bar` is updated in javascript.

How can I programmatically "push" my data into the model? (in my real app I'll be pushing data from the server via websockets / atmosphere)

Comment: [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

Answer (score 2):

If you use the angular $interval service instead of setInterval. Then you will not need to call $scope.$apply.

```
angular.module("controllers", [])
    .controller("FooController", function($scope, $interval) {
        $scope.foo = {};
        $scope.foo['bar'] = 0;
        $interval(function(){
            $scope.foo['bar']++;
        }, 100);
} );
```

Comment: The question is more about a general "push", not of solving the dummy setTimeout (as I wrote, the real app will use websocket push, in which case the apply will work, while interval won't be useful)

Answer (score 0):

You have to trigger a new `digest` cycle, in which Angular will check all the registered watches and update the view for objects that changed value. You can do it by calling `$scope.$apply`, which will trigger the digest cycle for you.

```
 setInterval(function(){
     $scope.$apply(function() {
         $scope.foo.bar++;
     })
 }, 100);
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is equivalent to `$interval`. It's not incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I've found the answer: wrap `$scope.foo['bar']++` into

```
$scope.$apply(function({
    $scope.foo['bar']++
}))
```